# Partial derivatives of Functions of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ be open and $(x_0,y_0)$ be an interior point in $D$. Let $f:D \to \mathbb R$ and $f$ has a local maxima or minima at $(x_0,y_0)$.

If $(u,v)\in \mathbb R^2$, $\lVert(u,v) \rVert = 1$ and $D_{(x_0, y_0)}f(u,v)$ exists, show that $D_{(x_0, y_0)}f(u,v)=0.$

Since $f$ has a local maxima or minima at $(x_0,y_0)$, can we say that $f_x(x_0,y_0)=f_y(x_0,y_0)=0?$ Because once, we have this, we can say that that $D_{(x_0,y_0)}f(u,v)=(f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0)).(u,v)$, implying the result.

Comment: Yup. I'll give you hints to the proof for your claim about the partials below.

Answer (score 1):

- Let $p = (a,b)$ be a local min or max. Define $g(x) = (x,b)$ and $h(y) = (a,b)$. Then $a,b$ are local min's or max's for $g,h$ respectively. From first-year calculus, what can you conclude about $g'(a)$ and $h'(b)$?
- Secondly, how do these derivatives relate to $f_x(p)$ and $f_y(p)$?
- Lastly, that assumption that $\|(u,v)\| = 1$ although not used, is there so that the definition of directional derivative (as we've defined in calc III) is well-defined.